# How to send text into the geolocation searchbox as per the url through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebgvO.png)

I am trying to enter a input (zipcode) into a store locator.

```
zipcode = input("What zip code would you like to search? ")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www2.dollargeneral.com/About-Us/pages/storelocator.aspx')
driver.maximize_window()
print "page accesses"

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='address']")
inputElement.send_key(zipcode)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I have also tried multiple different `select_by` methods within WebDriver. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction? I've used selenium a lot in the past, could it be that this is just not possible on this particular website? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='address']

Comment: looks like the store locator is embedded in an iframe, so you need to switch to that frame, try this driver.switch_to_frame("StoreLocator") before calling the address element.

Comment: You have to close the popup before sending the _zipcode_ to the searchbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smit9234 is correct -- you need to switch frames.   This works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

zipcode = "91307" #input("What zip code would you like to search? ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www2.dollargeneral.com/About-Us/pages/storelocator.aspx')


driver.switch_to_frame("StoreLocator") 
el = driver.find_element_by_id("address")

el.send_keys(zipcode)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this still doesn't enter in the zipcode into the search box

Comment: had to change to Chrome and download chromedriver. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence (zipcode) within the store locator searchbox you need to:

- First induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*
- Then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and invoke `click()`
- Finally again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and invoke `send_keys()`
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\GeckoDriver\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www2.dollargeneral.com/About-Us/pages/storelocator.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"StoreLocator")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.closeBtn>img[src='images/dollargeneral_new_bubble_close.png']"))).click()
  zipcode = input("What zip code would you like to search? ")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#address"))).send_keys(zipcode)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: zip]